# Check when vmsplice() has sent the buffer

Tags: c, linux, kernel

The system call vmsplice() allows zero copy send of user pages into a pipe.
However unless the call has specified that the buffer can be kept by the kernel, there is currently no way for the program to verify that the buffer has indeed been consumed by the pipe client, leading to the sender inadvertently writing over the submitted buffer.

So the question is: is there any way that the sender can verify that the entire buffer has been pushed to the client before it reuses the buffer?
As I see in code chef competition, the top answer using AVX2 is still overwriting the buffer and producing the wrong output in the reader side.

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/215216/high-throughput-fizz-buzz

Thank you.

Comment: See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html for how to get the number of unread bytes in the pipe buffer. See if it's 0?

Comment: HI Shaw, I ran some tests. That works on the inbound not outbound. My current assessment is that it's impossible to detect without writing a kernel module.